# CV Template "ReCeiVe" - Positioning, new line

Tags: positioning, templates, cv

I'm trying to make myself a new CV following this template I found online : https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/receive/dbzynfgjmxqy

And I'm only having one issue in order to be completely correct. My address is too big to fit inside the field reserved for it and therefore pushes the rest of the content out of the window.

I'd like to be able to for example break the line and keep the good looking aspect. Here's a quick look at the problem and at what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
\address{\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{My very long address which pushes everything out of the way}}
```

with `\makecvheader[L]`[image: a]

with `\makecvheader[C]`

[image: b]

I you want more room for the address put this code before `\begin{document}`

```
%%************************************* 
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\xpatchcmd{\makecvheader}
{0.4\@headerWidth}
{0.2\@headerWidth}
{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\makecvheader}
{0.6\@headerWidth}
{0.8\@headerWidth}
{}{}
%%**********************************
```

[image: c]

Comment: You're my savior, thank you!